# Create Function SQL-Server Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I am new to SQL Sg server and am trying to run code using the create function to convert a price fro USD to decimal. I'm getting the following flag

> "Incorrect Syntax: 'Create Function' must be the only statement in the
>   batch.

Can anyone point out what I'm dong wrong? Thank you!

```
CREATE FUNCTION week3.ConvertToEuro ( @priceUSD decimal(5,2))
returns decimal (5,2)

begin
        declare @PriceEuro decimal (5,2)
        set @PriceEuro =(@priceUSD * .89)
        return @PriceEuro

        end 

SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductName]
      ,[price]
      ,week3.ConvertToEuro(price) as PriceEuro
  FROM [AA5100_edmistonml].[Week3].[productprice]
```

Comment: Unless you're using SQL Server 2019 (and making use of inline scalar functionality), I would recommend an inline table-value function. Scalar function *can* be slow.

Comment: Exchange rate is likely to change, so better to make it a parameter (or query from up-to-date table).

Comment: @Larnu. . .  Side note `SQL Server 2019` is not yet released.

Comment: @YogeshSharma it's now in CTP 2.4, and (the preview) has been publically available for some time. Of course, that's why I stated "unless you're using 2019"; with the high likelihood they are not (especically as 2.4 is now only available as an evaluation version, and not developement/express).

Answer (score 2):

Both statements are different you either run separate or put `GO`  :

```
CREATE FUNCTION week3.ConvertToEuro ( @priceUSD decimal(5,2))
returns decimal (5,2)
begin
        declare @PriceEuro decimal (5,2)
        set @PriceEuro =(@priceUSD * .89)
        return @PriceEuro
end 

GO

SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductName], [price], week3.ConvertToEuro(price) as PriceEuro
FROM [AA5100_edmistonml].[Week3].[productprice];
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION week3.ConvertToEuro ( @priceUSD decimal(5,2))
returns decimal (5,2)
as -- add this 
begin
        declare @PriceEuro decimal (5,2)
        set @PriceEuro =(@priceUSD * .89)
        return @PriceEuro

        end 

go -- add this
SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductName]
      ,[price]
      ,week3.ConvertToEuro(price) as PriceEuro
  FROM [AA5100_edmistonml].[Week3].[productprice]
```

Comment: Hey Zaynul... Congratulations for being awarded the sql gold badge today... that's a great achievement, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try by creating `as` statement and add `go` between statements

```
CREATE FUNCTION week3.ConvertToEuro ( @priceUSD decimal(5,2))
returns decimal (5,2)
as  
begin
        declare @PriceEuro decimal (5,2)
        set @PriceEuro =(@priceUSD * .89)
        return @PriceEuro

        end 

go  
SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductName]
      ,[price]
      ,week3.ConvertToEuro(price) as PriceEuro
  FROM [AA5100_edmistonml].[Week3].[productprice]
```